# Ember route model blocks javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an `IndexRoute` and a `PricingRoute`, both are using the `plan` model in order to retrieve a list of plans from a JSON API. The models load just fine, there's no problem there.

I also have the `Google+ SDK` added on the `index.html` page. Also, the `Materialize` CSS library with a side-nav that is initialized through Javascript inside the `application controller`.

The problem is that whenever I refresh/initially load either of those 2 routes, the Google+ follow widget is not showing and the Materialize side-nav is not working (probably the JS init didn't work). However, if I just remove the model on the route (whichever of the 2), both the Google+ widget and the Materialize side-nav work as intended. So what exactly is wrong with the route model that it makes it interfere with the Google+ and Materialize libs ?

Worth noting is that I also have the Facebook lib initialized before the side-nav in the application controller, but that works just fine even with the models.

**application.js controller:**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  init: function ()
  {
    // initialize facebook SDK
    var facebook_id = this.facebook_app_id;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
    {
      FB.init({
        appId:   facebook_id,
        xfbml:   true,
        version: 'v2.1'
      });
    };
    (function (d, s, id)
    {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id))
      {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // load side nav drawer
    Ember.$(document).ready(function ()
    {
      Ember.$('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    });
  }
});
```

**index.js route:**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function ()
  {
    return this.store.find('plan');
  }
});
```

**pricing.js route:**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function ()
  {
    return this.store.find('plan');
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
...
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, initializing those view related stuffs in the controller is conceptually wrong.

It's not recommended to override the `init` method this way unless you do it right. Actually you are missing to call parent `init`.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  init: function ()
  {
      this._super(); // missing
```

Possibly the issue was, you are trying to initialize those modules before the view is inserted. Particularly, since the model call is *async*, the controller finishes init method before view has been inserted.

What you should be doing is,

```
// assuming you use ember-cli 
// views/application.js 
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    initLibs: function () {
        // do your initialization here
    }.on('didInsertElement')    
});
```

I'd also prefer the initialization of google+, the same way as you did for Facebook.

Comment: Indeed, the didInsertElement callback worked for initializing the libraries. What would be the difference between having the initialization inside the view didInsertElement vs the controller didInsertElement ?

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. I'm not entirely sure that the [controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html) class has an event called `didInsertElement` as [view does](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement). Moreover View's default [context](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_view-context) is the associated controller

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for the comprehensive explanations.